# Choices.js with Livewire for multiple select

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, choices.js

I'm new to Livewire after discovering it a few months back and I'm a bit rusty on Vanilla JS.

I have created a Livewire component to filter a table of news articles but I'm struggling to use the Choices.js library to select multiple categories and place them in to an array.

#### Livewire component:

```
public $filters = [
   ...
   'categories' => [],
   ...
];

public function render()
{
   $reports = Article::query()
      ->where('active', true)
      ->when($this->filters['categories'], function ($query, $category_ids) {
         $query->whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($category_ids) {
            $query->whereIn('category_id', $category_ids);
         });
      })
      ->get();

   $categories = Category::all();

   return view('livewire.reports.list-reports', compact('categories'));
}
```

#### Blade:

```
...
<div class="mb-2" wire:ignore>
   <label class="mb-1">Category</label>
   <select wire:model="filters.categories" class="form-control js-choice" multiple id="filter-categories">
   @foreach ($categories as $category)
      <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->type }}</option>
   @endforeach
   </select>
</div>
...
@section('page-scripts')
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/user/plugins/choices/choices.js') }}"></script>
@endsection
```

#### `choices.js` file:

```
import Choices from "choices.js";


const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.js-choice');

elements.forEach((item) => {
    const choices = new Choices(item, {
        removeItems: true,
        removeItemButton: true,
        searchEnabled: true,
        placeholder: true,
        placeholderValue: 'Select your options'
    });
    return choices;
});
```

### The problem

Without using `choices.js` and using the native browser multiple select box, it works perfectly fine, with the `filter.categories` property outputting `"categories": ["13","2","26"...]` and updating the controller query accordingly, displaying all news articles which have the selected category ID's.

But using `choices.js`, it only outputs the last clicked value and looks like this: `"categories": {"value":"13"}`. As it is not in an array, it simply just returns all of the news articles with an id of `13` in this instance. Clicking on multiple options just changes the property to the last clicked option. Also, clearing all of the options from the select box doesn't reset the `filters.categories` property back to empty, it just populates it with the ID of the last option that was closed.

How can I collect the ID's of the selected options and place them in to the `filter.categories` array and also remove them when I remove the item?

I know I need to put some logic in to the `choices.js` file to access the `detail.value` of the selected options but I'm really struggling to get it to work. I've explored Alpine as I believe this may be the key but I don't know where to start.

Any help is greatly appreciated, I've been stuck on this for a couple of days.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with choices.js so I'll do my best based on my experience using slimselect.js.

Basically when JS is applied to a select box it often abstracts away what you are actually clicking on, and those elements are already in a wire:ignore block so that part of the DOM is not reloaded.

So when I'm using something like you've described then I use the JS callback functions to set the properties of the Livewire Component.

In it's simplest form it will look something like this;

```
//where dataArray is the JS array you want to assign to the livewire component
@this.set(filters.categories, dataArray);
```

Just looking at the choices.js documentation you can use the 'choice' event.

```
const element = document.getElementById('filter-categories');
element.addEventListener(
  'choice',
  function(event) {
    //this is just selecting what the choices element's data is. not sure on syntax sorry.
    var dataArray = this.choices;
    @this.set(filters.categories, dataArray);
  },
  false,
);
```

Hope this helps